# How should men dress in Saudi Arabia to respect local law and morals?

Tags: saudi-arabia, dress-codes

What are acceptable items to wear for male tourists visiting Saudi Arabia, regardless of any religious affilation?

This is for everyday situations; not necessarily related to business or specific functions.

For instance, are T-shirts or shorts off-limits?

Comment: I can't speak for Saudi Arabia, having never visited the country, but in general I think it makes a significant difference whether a casual observer might think you were a local.  If your ethnicity is such that you might pass for a Saudi, you might be held to a higher standard than someone who was more obviously a visitor to the country.  That would be especially true if you also spoke the local language, here Arabic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Literally anything you would wear at your home country, you are free to wear whatever makes you comfortable.

Shorts are frowned upon at some malls and restaurants, yet people especially young ones are wearing them. T-shirts are the norm.

Unlike what most people think, there is no "religious" dress code.

I am a Saudi, who always wear jeans and t-shirts, I only wear the local thing when I have to, like in funerals, weddings, etc.. However, non-Saudis are not expected to wear the local dress for any occasion.

Note: As in many places around the world, nudity is not a good idea.

Note 2: Wearing @dabubianSailor's shorts is also frowned upon:
[image]

Comment: You probably underestimate what could be 'anything you would wear at your home country'....  Would shirtless or shorts exposing almost whole thighs also be OK?